# Second click does not work on jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a pop up that is asking the user whether to delete items from his contributions. It works when the user clicks the button for the first time. The pop up is opening an aspx file as a pop up by using jquery ui. However if the user clicks any other button ,in the second time, that triggers the same pop up it redirect to the page rather then opening it as a pop up: 
here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            function handler(e) {
                var page = $(this).attr("href")

                var $dialog = $('<div id="silmeIframe"></div>')
            .html('<iframe  style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="50px" height="50px"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 'auto',
                resizable: 'false',
                width: 'auto',
                title: "Silmeyi onaylıyor musunuz?",
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    __doPostBack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');
                }
            });

                $dialog.dialog('open');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('a#popup').on('click', handler);
            $('a#popup2').on('click', handler);


        });
    </script>
```